# not getting suitable output in fetching image and its description

Tags: php, css

I want to display images and their description(on hover) dynamically in a localhost application.

I am getting a vertical output:

[image: vertical output example]

but I want the images to be show horizontally (to a certain extent), like this:

[image: horizontal output example]

I tried the following

### PHP

```
    <?php
$c = mysql_connect("localhost", "abc", "xyz");
mysql_select_db("root");
$q     = "select * from product";
$qc    = mysql_query($q);
$count = 0;
while ($ans = mysql_fetch_array($qc)) {
    if ($count == 0 || $count == 1 || $count == 2) {
        
        $title = $ans[1] . " " . $ans[2];
        print '<div class="img-wrap">';
        print "<img id='display_img' src='products/$ans[8]'width=300 height=200 title='$title'>";
        print '<div class="img-overlay">';
        print '<h4>' . $title . '</h4>';
        print '<p>' . $ans[9] . '</p>';
        print '</div>';
        print '</div>';
    }
    $count++;
    if ($count == 3) {
        print "<br />";
        $count = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

### CSS

```
.img-wrap {
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    margin:10px;
}
.img-overlay {
    background-color:#000;
    bottom:0;
    color:#fff;
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1000;
    transition-duration:0.5s;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.img-overlay h4, .img-overlay p {
    padding:0 10px;
}
.img-wrap:hover .img-overlay {
    opacity:0.75;
    transition:opacity 0.5s;
}
b {
    background-color:#aa490e;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:36px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    padding-left:65px;
    padding-bottom:25px;
    font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}
```

Comment: PHP code is not relevant, next time post just generated HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing .img-wrap as following:

```
.img-wrap
{
float:left;
clear:none;
height:200px;
position:relative;
width:300px;
margin:10px;

}
```

Comment: this helps alot... but i want three image in a row to my page i am getting: http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/8939/o5g1.png

Answer (score 0):

You can add `display: inline-block` to `.img_wrap`:

```
.img-wrap {
    ...
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Or you can use `float: left`. But in this case make sure you `clear: both` after the last item.

http://jsfiddle.net/tRRVv/